# Query by Multiple ancestors in Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Is it possible to `load()` entities from multiple ancestor.
I have two `Kinds` 1- user, 2- post 
User is `ancestor` of post

I know how to apply ancestor query for single user like this
`ofy().load().type(Post.class).ancestor(user1).list();`
But how can apply query for multiple ancestors ?
Maybe something like this
 `ofy().load().type(Car.class).ancestors(user1,user2).list();`

Is it possible how can I do that if not what I do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Datastore not supports multi ancestor queries as well as OR operator. You will need to make two separate queries for that.